# Objects in 3D space: color contrast against background

Tags: color, color-scheme, 3d

Is there a tool to help me pick proper colors for:

1. Objects
2. Background

in 3D space. Colors should have proper contrast.

### UPDATE

A sample of my options for background color is:

Background color: `#c8c8c8c` , object color: `#576675`

[image: background color = #c8c8c8]

Background color: `#888888` , object color: `#576675`

[image: background color = #888888]

Background color: `#444444` , object color `#576675`

[image: background color: #444444]

### UPDATE

Any reference to research on this topic might help.

Comment: You would want to make the question more detailed. With an example or screenshot if possible would be great.! Thanks

Comment: @Kishan Examples are added to the post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tool/software recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is not related to text over a background not having to do with accessibility it remains a personal preference but it depends on what you want to achieve. You could refer to Gestalt principles.

This tool let`s you see what contrast works best for readability so it might give you a glance of what colors combine well to create a good contrast. 
https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/

Comment: Thanks. I think the link you provided is a good start to investigate the colors =)